# PyQT5 Data/View model representation with a complex widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to wrap my head around some ModelView on PyQT5.

I have a QListView, which can display data stored in an QAbstractListModel.

But i'd like to have each line of my QListView displaying a complex Widget created in QDesigner.

I've created a widget with a QLabel, a spacer, and a QPushButton.

[image]

I'd like to have each elements of my QListView using this widget to display my model data

Here is the basic code with a simple ModelView QListView

```py
import typing
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QListView


class MyListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data_list = []

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.data_list[index.row()]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self.data_list)

data = ["emotion", "unliving", "brutally", "torch", "donut", "comet"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    layout = QWidget()
    layout.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

    list_view = QListView()
    model = MyListModel()
    model.data_list = data
    list_view.setModel(model)

    layout.layout().addWidget(list_view)

    layout.resize(640, 480)
    layout.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried to create a QStyledItemDelegate, and set the delegate on the model, but i can't make it work.

```py
class LineDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.line = Ui_Form()
        self.line.setupUi(parent)

    def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: 'QStyleOptionViewItem', index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
    # Not sure what to put here
```

The doc seems to said that a Delegate should be used to edit data inside the view, not having a complex widget view.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/model-view-programming.html#a-simple-delegate

Is there anything possible to have what i want ?

I'm really not sure how to approch this.

Comment: Using a delegate is the preferred choice, normally. What have you tried that couldn't "make it work"?

Comment: I've tried to instantiate the widget inside the delegate, but i'm not sure how to do this "the good way", regarding the paint method.  

i've added the code in the main post.  

QT doesn't recommand to instantiate inside the paint method for performance concerns

Answer (score 0):

You must use a delegate so that you create an editor for each item, and then use the openPersistentEditor method to open the editors, it is not necessary to override the paint method.

```py
import typing

from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QListView,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class MyListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data_list = []

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.DisplayRole) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data_list[index.row()]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return len(self._data_list)

    @property
    def data_list(self):
        return self._data_list

    @data_list.setter
    def data_list(self, data_list):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data_list = data_list.copy()
        self.endResetModel()


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return Form(parent)

    """def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.label.setText(index.data())"""


data = ["emotion", "unliving", "brutally", "torch", "donut", "comet"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    list_view = QListView()
    model = MyListModel()
    model.data_list = data
    list_view.setModel(model)
    delegate = Delegate(list_view)
    list_view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for i in range(model.rowCount()):
        index = model.index(i, 0)
        list_view.openPersistentEditor(index)

    container = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
    layout.addWidget(list_view)
    container.resize(640, 480)
    container.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, got my windows displaying each rows as text. What is the point of the openPersistentEditor ? Is it necessary to force the creation of the delegate editor ? Your commented "setEditorData" makes the code not running at all if uncommented, i'll keep diging